# How can code that uses C FFI in Rust keep in sync with headers?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

For code (typically crates) that use FFI to wrap C code,
how is it possible to keep Rust definitions and C headers in sync? Or ensure they are matching to begin with?

Are there tools to handle this or is it the responsibility of each developer to manually check this?

Update: To make this more concrete.
Is there a way to know when:

- The member of a struct changes its type.
- A function argument changes its type.

So that any mis-match with the Rust code can warn or fail to compile entirely?

---

*I ran into a crash in a crate which I suspect is caused by API mismatch which remains reported but unfixed.*

Comment: Note, note sure why this question is marked as too board. - While there may be multiple answers... a way to keep Rust/C definitions in sync seems like a reasonable and well defined question.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1: bindgen

The [`bindgen!`](https://github.com/Yamakaky/rust-bindgen) module takes a C header file and generates Rust binding at compile time. Example [from the bindgen documentation](https://github.com/Yamakaky/rust-bindgen#generate-a-lua-binding-with-the-plugin):

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(bindgen)]

mod lua_bindings {
    bindgen!("/usr/include/lua.h", link="lua", builtins=true)
}
```

It adds `clang` as a complexity to your code and relies on rust nightly. Unfortunately that makes your project heavy (dependency wise) and bound to rust nightly, but it helps your FFI bindings staying up to date, plus the cross architecture issue boils down to know where the header files are for each architecture.

In my experience bindgen works pretty good, it has some limitations so it won't work for all cases.

## Solution 2: ctest

Another approach is taken by [Libc](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/). Libc consists basically of *only* FFI bindings for currently 18 supported architectures so it has a quite heavy requirement on correctness of FFI bindings.

In Libc the bindings are done by hand (often with the help of [running `bindgen` in commandline](https://github.com/Yamakaky/rust-bindgen#command-line)) and then tested against the header files using https://github.com/alexcrichton/ctest

How it works is that you specify all the C headers you want to check against and then the library compares it against the `extern fn` definitions you specifies in your code and makes sure..

> that all function signatures, constant values, struct layout/alignment, type size/alignment, etc, all match their C equivalent (quoted from [the docs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/ctest#how-it-works))

Throw travis into the mix and you can be sure your FFI bindings are correct for every code change across all supported architectures (have a look at [libc's pull requests](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/pulls) where every pull is automatically run through travis and lets the author correct all errors before the PR is merged).